# How can I delete this mysterious line in Indesign?

Tags: adobe-indesign

I received an Indesign document I need to work on. There is a line on the same layer as the text that I cannot delete:

[image]

[image]

The line stays in the same place within the text box and does not flow with the text.

I have checked for:
 - paragraph rules
 - paragraph borders
 - underline
 - locked objects
 - master pages

What could this be? How can I delete it?

Comment: Please show the entire page, in outline mode. We can’t make proper suggestions based on only a small part of the page.

Comment: For example: looking purely at its length, thickness, and awkward location (flush to the text at the top) this could very well be the line above a footnote, with its default settings. But we cannot see that because you cropped the image a bit too enthusiastic.

Comment: @usr2564301 That was what I thought too at first, but it looks like the text frame ends at the line; a footnote would be inside the frame too.

Comment: Ok, I added the whole page.

Answer (score 1):

Objects in InDesign are either:

- A) Part of text
- B) Separate elements unrelated to text

Determine which and adjust accordingly.

If you are unsure, it merely takes some deductive reasoning to determine where the object is.....

- Delete the text, is the element still there

  - YES: Then it's *not* part of the text formatting
  - NO: Then the element has been implemented via text formatting
- (undo the deletion)

If the object is not part of the text formatting, check layers. It's possible to have elements on various layers. Check for *locked objects* and *locked Layers*. It's possible lock objects in Indesign. Check Master Pages. Objects can be on master pages and not appear selectable on document pages.

If the object *is* part of the text formatting, then check paragraph rules, styles, etc.

No one here can blankety state *how* that element was created without examining the Indesign file.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like a footnote line. Check the text for footnotes and the footnote options (layout configuration), under Text menu.